Induced connection on principal bundle from associated vector bundle
Let $\pi: P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $(\rho, V)$ a finite-dimensional $G$-representation. In this article, a closed expression for the covariant derivative $\nabla: \Gamma(P \times_\rho V) \to \Gamma(P \times_\rho V \otimes T^\ast M)$ on the associated bundle induced by a connection form $\omega\in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ was presented:
Given $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ and $\sigma \in \Gamma(E)$, it is defined as
$$\nabla_X \sigma := \Phi(\mathcal{L}_{X^h}\Phi^{-1}(\sigma))$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lie derivative on $V$-valued functions, $X^h \in \Gamma(TP)$ is the unique horizontal lift of $X$ and $\Phi: C^\infty_G(P,V) \to \Gamma(P \times_\rho V)$ denotes the isomorphism between $G$-equivariant $V$-valued functions on $P$ and sections of the associated bundle.
Now I am interested if there is a similar closed expression for connection forms on $P$ induced by covariant derivatives on an associated bundle which also does not make use of any non-canonical choices, such as local sections. If anyone could point me to resources or give me such an expression, I would be very grateful.

How does a covariant derivative on an associated bundle induce a principal connection on $P$? For example if $g\mapsto 1\in\text{GL}(1,\mathbb{R})$ and the latter is equipped with the exterior derivative, what's the induced connection on $P$? Seems to me that this would define a "preferred" connection on any principal $G$-bundle, and I don't believe such a thing exists.

@Quaere Verum It indeed does! See e.g. Chapter 8 Addendum 3 of Spivak's "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry" Vol. 2

No, that section just contains a summary of the relation between principal connections on $\text{Fr}(E)$ and linear connections on $E$. That does not imply that a linear connection on $E_\rho$ induces a principal connection on $P$ for an arbitrary representation $\rho$.

You're absolutely right! Sorry! Thanks for pointing that out
